# How can I add cover vertical animation while changing rootViewController

Tags: swift

I can add animation from options. But none of them are cover vertical. How can add cover vertical animation ?

```
 guard let window =  UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else {
                return
            }

            guard let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "x") as! xTabBarController
            vc.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
            vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                window.rootViewController = vc
            }, completion: { completed in
                
            })
```

Comment: You need something to cover! Settings `window.rootViewController` directly is not like presenting a new controller. Present  something and replace the root after the animation.

Comment: let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    
let transition = CATransition()
transition.type = .push
transition.subtype = .fromTop
    
let window = self.view.window
window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible() I did like this and it works I think